# Skecth the root locus with respect to K for the characteristic equation.

Tags: polynomials, roots

$$s^4+12s^3+22s^2+(20+K)s+2K=0$$

I don't understand, how can I sketch the root locus? Can anybody help me to understand?

Comment: It might help if you told us what this characteristic equation is describing. Some linear differential equation? A recurrence relation? A linear transformation's eigenvalues?

Comment: Cameron, root locus is a term used in control theory to describe how the "roots" of an equation move with respect to a parameter.  The characteristic equation is for a linear-time invariant system (linear constant coefficient ODE) with a parameter, usually a "gain" in control theory.  The characteristic equation is for the eigenvalues of that system.  The above is interpreted as being in the Laplace-transform domain of the original ODE in time.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you present has "roots" with respect to $s$, that is, values of $s$ that cause the equation to be satisfied (values that make the left-hand side zero).  However, as you change the gain $K$, those roots move around in the complex $s$-plane.  The "locus" of all the points in the complex plane where the roots move around as $K$ changes are called the root locus.

There are rules for sketching these things by hand.  Usually though you have numerator and denominator, or an open loop transfer function.  Are you sure you have presented us with all of the information you are given?

Comment: The teacher told me ,but i still have a problem about skecthing root locus.